# Adding dependency as DLL or adding as a project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

We have an application written in asp.net mvc.

Now we have written common db context & entities module (2 projects/class library) which are required by this application. Same db context and entities would also be required /part of another application.

Now my question is how to add this common project to our applications.

Should we add it as a dll or should be add them as separate projects in each solution referencing the common project. Any pros cons of above approach. Or if there is a better approach to handle this.

Thanks
Jas

Comment: You should never just have the raw DLL as a dependency. If you decide to have that in separate source control, then you should pass it around via a versioned NuGet package. Of course, whether you have everything in the same repository and project is up to you, there's advantages and disadvantages to both ways and the only one who really make the decision is you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather go with a separate project within the same solution, or at worst you could create a NuGet module with some custom registrations that you need to add to each project as you need.

Currently what I do in my own project is something like this.

```
Solution
  App.Data
  App.API
  App.ServiceWorker
```

...where data is common to API & ServiceWorkers
and then have our super generic modules that are also distributed (internally) via Nuget for re-use (but make sure they're able to function as isolated pieces)... to re-iterate as @masosn's comment suggested, don't just use the draw dll if you can avoid it.

Comment: If your Data is also required in another project dont you think that you have to maintain separate multiple copies of data. Again as I mention to gentlemen in the post above. What if we have multiple dev working on multiple projects that have this Data project and dont update it across and use the older version.

Comment: For sure, in that use case I'd go the NuGet module route. Currently have have about 20 modules that get shared across 4 separate projects like this, and, each of them registers their own internal services/or require a certain db context. Just provide at a per project level the connection string of the source that you wish each module to connect to.

Comment: Ok have to look into creating local nuget packages. I hope I can create that will our local repositories like svn, tfs etc.

Comment: Yeah :) Erm, as an fyi: we use something called, appveyor for our NPM modules (so our modules are protected & you need credentials before you can even see them within NuGet)... but I'm sure there are other similar services that can host you packages for you.

Comment: One more thing... can we make the common project as readonly and add it to the projects which needs them. By making it read only other applications where this project has been added wont be able to edit it. So only in the parent project which created it can edit it. Not sure if this is possible

Comment: If its internal to the solution. No, if its a NuGet package then yes (ilt'll be "read only"). But if you have access to the source you can edit it (unless there is some functionality that I'm not aware of)

Comment: I got everything setup, created nuget package and was able to add to my project. Just one thing how do you maintain versioning. Say I update my nuget project. How do we change version and shows up in nuget. I changed the version no in the nuspec file and then created the nuget package but it still does not shows the updated version

Answer (score 2):

It depends largely on how these applications are expected to grow together. How likely are you to make a change in your data application that will break the consuming code in your other applications? If this is likely to happen frequently, I'd keep all these projects in the same Solution and Repository, and use Project references. This makes refactoring much easier, since Visual Studio will be aware of all the usages of a given class or member in all of your down-stream dependencies.

However, if the data layer is pretty well hardened at this point, and you may need to have the different applications deployed using different versions of it (which I find unlikely) then you should deploy your Data project as a Nuget package. That way, each application can specify which version it knows about, and can make sure it's always compatible with the version that it specifies.

I agree with the other commenters/answerers, that you should not create a dependency on the DLL directly. That's a really old-school way of managing things that doesn't scale well with newer version control technologies.

Comment: The common project is bound to change frequently as more applications come in or we add more functionality. My concern with maintaining local copies in each application was that there would be multiple versions of one project in different applications. And many times could be a case one developer not updating it and is working off an older version.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like keeping things together in a single solution in a single repository is probably the way to go. That way the shared project is automatically updated every time the developer pulls the latest code.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you'd want to reference a library project, not a DLL. You may keep all the projects in the same solution or use a private nuget repo like the others have mentioned.

However sharing a `DbContext` is not a good idea, because once you have a new migration all the projects using the shared `DbContext` will have to be redeployed. It's also not a good idea because you don't want multiple projects to be responsible for the data in your datastore.

Though this might require some restructuring, you might want to look into microservice architecture. Each microservice would be responsible for its datastore alone.